# AngularJS # in URL - does not work with links to new tabs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am working on a project that has the routing set up to read from the URL hash, e.g. `localhost:9000/#/path/to/page` (to be exact, I can't find any configs about this, seems like this is just unchanged default behavior).

Everything works fine, except one thing - if there are any ui-sref links, they will not open correctly in a new tab, i.e. `<a ui-sref="path.to.page" target="_blank">` will open in a new tab with URL=`localhost:9000/path/to/page` (note the missing `/#`).
Clicking them works fine for some reason, but not opening in a new tab.

Any ideas on how to solve this? It would be very useful in many places to have a normal link that can be opened both in current or new tab.

Edit: found a bug about this, but the only suggestion is to use an old version until new one fixes it: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1499
I'm using Angular 1.5.7, so this bug should have been fixed already.

Comment: Have you tried using Html5 mode? That would remove the #. Docs: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions.

Comment: Yeah, that should work, but it requires changes both in code and in backend, so would need to be synchronized. Is it really not possible to fix it only in frontend (I'm not bothered by the /#)?

Comment: For now, I've implemented a directive that replaces ui-sref and just adds a normal href attribute to the anchor.